# Non linear animation makes my keyframes edit very difficult

Tags: animation

So i have multiple nla layers, i can't edit any of animations without my rig to be in a messed up position during the editing of keyframes.
Another problem is that I can't add other animation on the same bone on wich i already have an non liniar animation.

Comment: To edit an action you neef to select a NLA strip and press Tab, the action will appear in the Dope Sheet, is it what you're doing?

Comment: Yes i hit tab in nla to edit it. but it changes the rig position when i edit it and for some reason after i hit tab back again it comes back to normal.... The idea is i somehow managed to make it work but from 10 non linear animations they no longer work when i edit one of them or i cant add more keyframes becouse one of those nla actions will refuse to work till i delete the new made keyframes...

Comment: Have you pinned the strip (the pin icon in the left panel)?

Comment: Yes they are pinned.

Comment: Maybe show some screenshots or share your file (at least a part of it)